# Trouble downloading non CRAN packages

Tags: r

I want to download https://github.com/AdrianAntico/RemixAutoML however I get an error that the package CatBoost (which is a dependency of RemixAutoML)
Error: unable to access index for repository https://github.com/catboost/catboost/tree/master/catboost/R-package/src/contrib

So I tried to download it manually from 'https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases/download/v0.6.1.1/catboost-R-Windows-0.6.1.1.tgz' but I get Error:

> Error in findpack(package, lib.loc) : 
>     there is no package called 'catboost'
>   Calls:  -> findpack
>   Execution halted
>   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'catboost'
>   * removing 'FilePath'
>   Error in i.p(...) : 
>     (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/jarlan/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpoJEuqk/file20e059cf378c/catboost_0.6.1.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I don't know what to do.

````
This is the code I ran 
```{r}

#Code that was part of the instructions for downloading RemixAutoML 
to_install <- c("catboost", "caTools", "data.table", "doParallel", "foreach", "forecast", "ggplot2", "h2o", "itertools", "lubridate", "monreg", "pROC", "RColorBrewer", "recommenderlab", "ROCR", "scatterplot3d", "stringr", "tm", "tsoutliers", "wordcloud", "xgboost", "zoo")
for (i in to_install) {
  message(paste("looking for ", i))
  if(i == "catboost" & !requireNamespace(i)) {
    devtools::install_url('https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases/download/v0.6.1.1/catboost-R-Windows-0.6.1.1.tgz')
  } else if(i == "h2o" & !requireNamespace(i)) {
    if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
    if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }
    pkgs <- c("RCurl","jsonlite")
    for (pkg in pkgs) {
      if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
    }
    install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-yates/3/R")
  } else if (!requireNamespace(i)) {
    message(paste("     installing", i))
    install.packages(i)
  }
}
#now to install the package
devtools::install_github('AdrianAntico/RemixAutoML', force = TRUE, dependencies = TRUE, upgrade = FALSE)
````

Comment: -arch           x86_64                      
-os             mingw32                     
-system         x86_64, mingw32                                    
-major          3                           
-minor          6.0                                         
-svn rev        76424

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the problem is the package `catboost` i remove this package of the code thath your put and i achieved to install the other packages,

```
        to_install <- c("caTools", "data.table", "doParallel", "foreach", "forecast", "ggplot2", "h2o", "itertools", "lubridate", "monreg", "pROC", "RColorBrewer", "recommenderlab", "ROCR", "scatterplot3d", "stringr", "tm", "tsoutliers", "wordcloud", "xgboost", "zoo")

for (i in to_install) {message(paste("looking for ", i))if(i == "catboost" &
    !requireNamespace(i)) {devtools::install_url('https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases/download/v0.6.1.1/catboost-R-Windows-0.6.1.1.tgz')
      } else if(i == "h2o" & !requireNamespace(i)) {
        if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
        if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }
        pkgs <- c("RCurl","jsonlite")
        for (pkg in pkgs) {
          if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
        }
        install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-yates/3/R")
      } else if (!requireNamespace(i)) {
        message(paste("     installing", i))
        install.packages(i)
      }
    }
```

after that you need to install `catboost` manually 
`library(devtools) devtools::install_url('https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases/download/v0.6.1.1/catboost-R-Windows-0.6.1.1.tgz', 
args = c("--no-multiarch"))`

hence you can run

```
 # Depending on the development state (future versions, etc.) you can install via:
devtools::install_github('AdrianAntico/RemixAutoML', upgrade = FALSE)
devtools::install_github('AdrianAntico/RemixAutoML', upgrade = FALSE, dependencies = FALSE, force = TRUE)
```

and this is all, if you didn´t have luck install catboost from the link above try with other that you find maybe you need to try several times this is the more difficult part of the process.